# Generate a 2-fps mp4 from images using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, frame-rate, video-conversion

Need to create a video from a series of images. The video needs to have a low frame rate. This is the command I use to create the video.

```
ffmpeg.exe -r 2 -i images/%3d.jpg -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p output.mp4
```

The problem is that, while the video works just fine when played through a HTML5 video, it doesn't really work when the file is downloaded locally and played through either the Windows 10 default video player or even VLC (weirdly, the default video player works better).

Can anyone explain why this is happening and possibly how to fix the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some players, like VLC, don't like low framerate videos.

Use

```
ffmpeg.exe -framerate 2 -i images/%3d.jpg -r 8 -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuvj420p output.mp4
```

Each frame will still last for 0.5 seconds but output rate is 8 which should play in VLC.

Comment: not sure I understand what is happening. The frame rate of the video is set to 2 (0.5 seconds per frame), but `-r 8` set the video length to be 8 seconds?

Comment: Oh, never mind. For whatever reason running this command via a process in .NET and just doing it manually in powershell returns two different results...

Comment: Ah, I'm a dummy. Had `-r 8` right after `-framerate 2` instead of after `-i images`. Thanks, that worked!